# Terminal Missing in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I opened Android Studio to find that the Terminal Tab is no longer present along the bottom left. Restoring to the default layout did not return it. I also can't seem to find any reference to it in the View or Window Tabs.

How do I get the to the Terminal tab in Android Studio?

Update:

Terminal is not present under View -> Tool Windows, but the Terminal Plugin is installed and enabled.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
File > Settings > Plugins' - Search for "terminal"
```

Untick the check box -> Press Apply
Tick it again -> Press Apply -> Press OK
Restart Studio

Answer (score 9):

Try the shortcut alt+F12. Or check the information under the heading

> Running embedded local terminal

On the following link:[jetbrains help](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/working-with-embedded-local-terminal.html)

Comment: See the update on the question, a new twist has been added.

Answer (score 1):

Toggling `Tools-> Android-> Enable ADB Integration` Off/On then restarting the IDE returned my Terminal Tab.